# How to display "Unit of Measure" field on Product form in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, product, odoo-10

In Odoo v8 there is a Unit of Measure field on the Product form:
[Product form Odoo v8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJcUM.png)

But it's not on the same form in Odoo v10:
[Product form Odoo v10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1E5Z.png)

How can I display this field in Odoo 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go in the Settings part of Sale and click the Settings menu. There you'll find a lot of options to choose from. Utlimately you'll want to check the radio button next to the unit of measure title allowing you to choose different unit of measures on sales and purchases.

Similar settings can be found on the Purchase and Inventory management modules. Sorry if the names don't exactly match yours, I'm using Odoo in French and am translating on the fly.

Comment: thanks, Majikat! There are two radio buttons over against the Units of Measure settings: 1) Products have only one unit of measure (easier); 2) Some products may be sold/purchased in different units of measure (advanced).
So I switched to 2nd one and it added two fields on the Product form: Unit of Measure and Purchase Unit of Measure.

Answer (score 0):

click on Inventory > Configuration > Settings and find this:
[picture guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iVW1.png)

make sure your unit of measure setting is "Some products may be sold/purchased in different units of measure (advanced)"